# ejs is showing my response.locals variable undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I want to loop through names array and show all speakers data in a dropdown menu.

```
app.use(async (request, response, next) => {
    try {
        const names = await speakersService.getNames();
        response.locals.speakerNames = names;
        console.log(response.locals);
        return next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return next(error);
    }
});
```

here is my index.ejs file where I want to add speakerNames array.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/speakers">All Speakers</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                        <% speakerNames.forEach( function (speaker) {%>
                            <a 
                            class="dropdown-item" 
                            href="/speakers/<%=speaker.shortname%>">
                                <%=speaker.name%>
                            </a>
                            <%})%>
                    </div>
```

but it shows this error message

```
 >> 21|                         <% speakerNames.forEach( function (speaker) {%>

    22|                             <a class="dropdown-item" href="/speakers/<%=speaker.shortname%>">

    23|                                 <%=speaker.name%>

    24|                             </a>


speakerNames is not defined
```

here is the code for res.render is used

```
export default (params) => {
    const { speakersService } = params;
    router.get('/', async (request, response) => {
        const topSpeakers = await speakersService.getList();
        console.log(topSpeakers);
        response.render('layout', { pageTitle: 'Welcome', template: 'index', topSpeakers });
    });

    router.use('/speakers', speakerRouter(params));
    router.use('/feedback', feedbackRouter(params));
    return router;
};
```

Comment: Show the code that calls `res.render`

Comment: i have edited the code and added res.reder file code

Comment: I am facing same issue for topSpeakers too...

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting `undefined` from `speakersService.getList();`? cause everything else seems fine